# How to split a string at only . and not if it is preceded by double slash?

Tags: java, regex, string

i'm using the regex `\/\/[.]` to match `//.` in a String.

> This is//. a .example .String

If we split the above String at dot the output should be

`This is//. a 
example 
String`

What is the regular expression for the String.split() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to split a string with a dot not immediately preceded with  `//` string.

Use

```
.split("(?<!//)\\.")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sVwKOi/1)

The `(?<!//)` is a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a `//` text immediately to the left of the current location.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String str="This is//. a .example .String";
        String[] strArr=str.split("[^//.]\\.");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strArr));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[This is//. a, example, String]
```

**Explanation:** You use negated character classes to exclude certain characters: e.g. `[^abcde]` matches anything but a,b,c,d,e characters.

Answer (score 0):

In `split()` method you can pass `\\.` as `String.split("\\.")`

Answer (score 0):

How about split on `dot` if not preceded with `/`

```
String.split("\w*(?<!//)\\.")
```